# Why winform filckers on button click event

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have winform app which has 3 forms, in 2 forms I am taking user inputs and `when user click button my form flickers (i means its like form disappear and appears, and sometimes sends my app to back of other app)`. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my application? Has anyone faced this kind of strange behavior in winform?

`EDITED`

```
Cursor currentCursor = this.Cursor;
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.btnSave.Enabled = false;
            if (isDataModified)
            {
                if (CheckMandatoryData(mpgUserInfo, ref errorMessage))
                {
                    AppMessageBoxResult appMessageBoxResult =
                        AppMessageBox.ShowQuestion("Confirmation",
                    "Do you want to continue?", Environment.NewLine));

                    if (appMessageBoxResult == AppMessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        if (customerInformation != null)
                        {
                            //Assigning value to variable and saving
                            RefreshData();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    AppMessageBoxResult appMessageBoxResult =
                        AppMessageBox.ShowQuestion("Confirmation",
                        "Do you want to continue to save?",
                        errorMessage, Environment.NewLine));

                    if (appMessageBoxResult == AppMessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        if (customerInformation != null)
                        {
                            //Assigning value to variable and saving
                            RefreshData();
                        }
                    }
                    errorMessage.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
    AppMessageBox.ShowException("Error", exception.Message, 
               exception.InnerException.Message, exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = currentCursor;
            this.btnSave.Enabled = true;
        }
```

here `AppMessageBox` is our extended `MessageBox` and is part of our custom framework.

Comment: It's hard to help without an idea of what the code in the button does... can you post something?

Comment: Could you post the button click handler?

Comment: I have added code which is being executed on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having focus / modal dialog issues in your AppMessageBox

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to check that, because I have dll of framework.